# Custom plugin places html head content in body

Tags: plugins, pages

I'm currently working on a plugin. I have to render a lot of html on a specific page. I've placed that piece of code in the plugin it's core file, like so:

```
    add_filter('the_content', 'overwrite_content');
 
function overwrite_content($content) {
    if(is_page('Signup')){
        require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/views/signup.php');
        $content = '';
    }
    else if(is_page('Bedankt')){
        require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/views/thanks.php');
        $content = '';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

It all works fine, but for some reason all `<head>` elements are being placed underneath my custom html within the `<body>` think of `<meta, <title> etc`.

Does anyone know how I fix this?
I'd rather skip creating a shortcode, since the html is just simply too much.

Comment: you can't insert HTML into the `<head>` tag from inside a shortcode or from `the_content` filter, and you shouldn't be outputting HTML directly to the browser inside that filter, you need to return it instead. Otherwise that output happens immediatley, not at the location the filtered HTML is used

Comment: I know I can't insert HTML into the `<head>` . But in what way returning do you mean? Like `return '<div>test</div>';`?

Comment: yes, by calling `require_once` you're outputting directly to the browser any templates/tags the same way `print` or `echo` does. That way the output of those files is immediately sent when they're executed

Comment: Ah okay, than I know return will do the trick. But what if my HTML has like atleast 200 lines. Doesn't it become too big of a return?

Comment: that's a PHP problem, with lots of other solutions unrelated to WordPress, e.g. output buffers, Eitherway PHP won't change how it works to make 200+ lines more convenient. Keep in mind too that the solution you chose to put your code into the template of filtering the content and title is not the only method available. The general gist I was trying to say though, is if you want to add `meta`/`title` tags etc to the page, the content filter or a shortcode are far too late, it needs to happen much earlier while WP outputs the header

Comment: I don't want to add some meta tags etc. I was more trying to say that due to using `require_once` that it first loads my content, and later after that the rest of the WP content. which means all elements from `<head>` are now underneath my html somewhere in the `<body>` which means I need another render method for my form.php